# Google calendars no longer showing events on PUBLIC calendars

Tags: events, calendar, hidden

We use iframes to display our senior events calendars and up until today, they were working fine. All of them are set to Public but no one can view events, even if they are logged into Google, they're all blank!

#### Admin console showing Make Public is checked

[image: admin console showing Make Public is checked]

#### Admin console showing actual events

[image: admin console showing actual events]

#### Actual web page where iframe is used - everything blank

[image: actual web page where iframe is used - everything blank]

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I’m on the same boat and can’t find any answers online to mitigate this issue